# Why do we call $x$ a constant while mentioning eigenfunctions of the position operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

For a position eigenstate $\psi_x$, we say $$\hat{x}\psi_x=x\psi_x$$
Since it's an eigenfunction, we say that the result of using the operator is "a constant times the function itself". But $x$ isn't a constant, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

- $\psi_x$ is a function of position, i.e. if you write it when actually evaluated it reads $\psi_x(x')$, where $x'$ is the position the function is evaluated at.
- For the vast majority of functions $f$, evaluating $\hat xf$ at $x'$ yields $(\hat x f)(x') = x'\,f(x')$, i.e. you're multiplying by $x'$ itself.
- On the other hand, for the position eigenstates $\psi_x$, you get $(\hat x\psi_x)(x') = (x\psi_x)(x') = x\, \psi_x(x')$, where the multiplier $x$ does not depend on the argument $x'$, i.e. it is a constant.
- To be clear, it is *also* true that $(\hat x\psi_x)(x') = (x\psi_x)(x') = x'\, \psi_x(x')$. This is achieved since $\psi_x(x')$ is zero at all places except where the argument $x'$ matches the pre-specified $x$.

Obviously $x$ is also a variable, which ranges over the entire real axis. But when you're talking about $\psi_x$, which is specific to $x$, that variable is effectively fixed. The argument is repeated over and over, with equal validity, for all possible $x$s you might choose, but within each of those arguments the value of $x$ is essentially fixed. This is what it means to say things like

> Let $x\in \mathbb R$ and let $\psi_x$ be the eigenstate of $\hat x$ with eigenvalue $x$

$-$ it completely encapsulates the variability in $x$ from that point onward, and those parts of the argument need to treat $x$ as a fixed, given number.

Comment: This means that it is wrong to say "for a position eigenfunction $\psi(x,t)$, we have $\hat{x}\psi(x,t)=x\psi(x,t)$"?

Comment: No, that is not wrong (but you shouldn't write it like that unless you really understand the difference and why it's not wrong). See the fourth bullet point for details.